# Uploadify - Upload large file (about 700 MB) with microsoft IIs and PHP

Tags: php, iis

If I select a large file (about 700 MB), it will begin to Upload, and then after a while the progress bar to restart from zero percent and resume the Upload at the beginning. Afterwords around 17 minutes to Upload it again from the beginning.
Why? Thank you for your help.

Here are my parameters:

Uploadify setting:

```
-self.uploadify ({
".swf": "Uploadify.swf '
"Upload": "upload.php '
'FormData': {'action', 'upload', 'path': self.attr ('path')}
'QueueID': customQueueId,
"FileTypeExts ':' * *."
"FileTypeDesc": "All Files"
'ButtonImg': buttonImg,
"Main" 'ButtonCursor'
'ButtonText': '',
'ScriptAccess': "always",
"Method", "post"
'Width': bwidth,
"Height": bheight,
'FileSizeLimit' :"50000MB",
'QueueSizeLimit': 100,
'Auto' (self.attr ("auto") == "false" false: true)
"Multi" (self.attr ("multi") == "true" true: false)
'PreventCaching': false,
'RemoveCompleted': true,
"Debug": true,
'OnFallback': function () {
alert ("not flash installed in your browser.");
},
```

Php.ini:

```
max_execution_time = 300000
max_input_time = 600000
memory_limit = 128M
On file_uploads =on
upload_max_filesize = 5G
max_file_uploads = 100
```

Setting IIS:

```
<? xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
<System.webServer>
<HttpErrors ErrorMode = "detailed" />
<Security>
<RequestFiltering>
<RequestLimits maxAllowedContentLength = "4000000000" />
</ RequestFiltering>
</ Security>
</system.webServer>
<System.web>
<HttpRuntime executionTimeout = "172806600" />
</system.web>
</ Configuration>
```

Comment: upload and download are not the same! if you have a download problem, max_upload in php.ini didn't fetch

Comment: Thank you. It's Upload problem and not download.

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://blogs.iis.net/donraman/troubleshoot-my-php-script-is-timing-out

Comment: Thank you very much for this new response that was very helpful . I changed the ActivityTimeout and RequestTimeout in FastCGI and it works now .